# C# Performance Counter Object reference not set to an instance to an object

Tags: c#

I was coding on my project and wanted to debug it, but I got this error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance to an object
>   NullReferenceExpection was unhandled

My program was working and I had this error for a few days. There I solved the problem with, I think, with typing something in my windows console. I think I reseted the Performance Counter and then it worked.

Here is the code:

```
public void Counter()
{
    counter = new PerformanceCounter();
    counter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    counter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    counter.InstanceName = "_Total";
}

public double GetCounter()
{
    return counter.NextValue();  //error message is in this line
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code around the place the exception is occuring on.

Comment: hm i don't think that it is necessary to post the file because it is a general problem of the performance counter, but i will add it

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint there, is `counter == null` ?

Comment: yes, but how can i change this?

Comment: It seems like the code currently in `void Counter()` should be moved to the constructor, or at least this method should be called in the constructor for your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to help you without more information but I will try to tell you how to figure out the problem yourself.

You should look in the stack trace to get the line of code that threw the error.  This should show you what is going wrong.